# Einstein's energy equation

Tags: mass-energy

My question is - According to Einstein's Energy Mass Equivalence, $E=mc^2$ , a small mass can be converted into large amount of energy (atomic bomb). Is there an example of energy converted into mass (apart from the big bang theory)?

Comment: [Pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good examples to demonstrate Einstein's mass-energy relation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78119/)

Comment: FYI: you could have said "candle flame" instead of "atomic bomb," and it would not change the meaning of what you said in the slightest amount.